# How to receive XML in ASP.NET Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, security

I have a quasi-RESTful ASP.NET web service that I wish to be able to post XML to. My method looks something like this:

```
[WebMethod(false, System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionOption.NotSupported)]
public void save(string saveXml)
{
    XDocument saveXml = XDocument.Parse(saveXml);
    ....
```

When I try to post to that web service, I get the exception:

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form
value was detected from the client...
```

Based on some searching, my understanding is that *all* requests to ASP.NET pages look for characters like "<" which are deemed dangerous (obviously this applies to my XML). This can be turned off easily for individual pages, but not web services. The only solution I have found involved changing the request validation mode in my web.config to "2.0". I don't want to change to an old version of something just because my one web service method doesn't work with the 4.0 version. Is there any way to disable this for my specific method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also base64 encode the XML string. En/decoding base64 is trivial and avoids this kind of configuration headache.

Comment: What kind of client will be posting to this service? How are you posting when you get this exception?

Comment: Also, this may be a hint that it's time to stop using ASP.NET Web Services, which are a "legacy technology".

Comment: @John Saunders: The client is a Flex application. I realize there are several other better alternatives, but due to time constraints I must use what is already set up in our application.

Comment: Is the web service in a separate IIS application? This exception comes in an attempt to protect your web site. If the service were in a different application from the site, then you would not get the error.

Comment: @John Saunders: No, the web service is in the same application as the rest of the site.

Comment: I'm recommending that you move it out. It has different settings from the rest of the application. The setting for request validation is the first example of this that you have seen. There may be more such differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new 4.0 RequestValidation model is a bit pickier, but as long as your client sends the HTTP request `Content-type` header as `text/xml` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it should pass (or bypass rather) ASP.NET RequestValidation.